# Remove cells that do not meet condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[image]I want to remove races (which are less than 1%) in a county.
I am using pandas. If you notice some races have values less than 1% in a county. I want to ignore those race and display races with higher populations

```
CensusTract State   County  TotalPop    Men   Women Hispanic    White   Black   Native  Asian   Pacific
1001020100  Alabama Autauga  1948       940   1008     0.9      87.4    7.7      0.3    0.6      0
1001020400  Alabama Autauga  4423       2172  2251     10.5     82.8    3.7      1.6    0        0
```

I tried this

```
dataset = tract_data.query("Income >= 50000 & Poverty > 50")

dataset.loc[:,'Races'] = dataset.apply(lambda row: list(zip(list(row.index) 
[6:12], list(row)[6:12])), axis =1)
dataset.loc[:,'Races'] = dataset.Races.apply(lambda x: '; '.join(['{}: 
{}'.format(t[0], t[1]) for t in  list(filter(lambda x: x[1]> 1, x))]))
income = dataset[['CensusTract', 'State', 'County','Races']]

print(dataset['Races'])
```

But I still have error

This is what I expect to have

```
CensusTract State       County  races
1001020100 Alabama Autauga White: 87.4 Black: 7.7
1001020400 Alabama Autauga Hispanic: 10.5 White: 82.8 Black: 3.7 Native: 1.6
```

Comment: What did you try? `df.where()` is one example you could use to filter here

Comment: I did this dataset = dataset.where("Hispanic > 1 & White > 1 & Black > 1 & Native > 1 & Asian > 1 & Pacific > 1")  and I was getting errors

Comment: Ok, but if any of the ands fail, it wouldn't filter right?

Comment: @user8834780 It gives me error when I run that

Comment: The problem with what you want is a different shape of dataframe for every row. Could you post some more inform about how you plan to use the data?

Comment: What do you mean @Polkaguy6000

Comment: 1001020100 has two rows, but 1001020400 has three rows. How do you expect both of these to fit into the same dataframe?

Comment: I don't, that's why I'm asking for help on how to do that or print what I want

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to achieve your goal

```
df['Races'] = df.apply(lambda row: list(zip(list(row.index)[6:], list(row)[6:])), axis =1)
df['Races'] = df.Races.apply(lambda x: '; '.join(['{}: {}'.format(t[0], t[1]) for t in  list(filter(lambda x: x[1]> 1, x))]))
```

Finally, if we print `df`, here is what we get.

```
    CensusTract State   County  TotalPop    Men Women   Hispanic    White   Black   Native  Asian   Pacific Races
0   1001020100  Alabama Autauga 1948    940     1008    0.9         87.4    7.7      0.3       0.6     0.0  White: 87.4; Black: 7.7
1   1001020400  Alabama Autauga 4423    2172    2251    10.5        82.8    3.7      1.6       0.0     0.0  Hispanic: 10.5; White: 82.8; Black: 3.7; Nativ...
```

Here is the idea. The values we want to compare are in the 6th to the last columns. For each row, we want to show the row name as well as the value in it if the value is greater than 1. Now `list(row.index)` gives us the column names for that row and `list(row)` gives us the values in that row as list. We can zip these list to get a list of tuples `[(column_name, value)]`.

Then we can filter the list of tuples by `key = value` to contain only the tuples where `value` is greater than 1. After filtering, we will get a list of tuples and the rest of the work is just to format the list of tuples to display an answer in a manner that we love. To understand how the filtering is works, just try:

```
x = [('col1', 8), ('col2', 10), ('col3', 0.9), ('col4', 30)]
'; '.join(['{}: {}'.format(t[0], t[1]) for t in  list(filter(lambda x: x[1]> 1, x))])
```

The result should be;

```
>>> 'col1: 8; col2: 10; col4: 30'
```

Comment: TypeError: (> not supported btw instances of str and int)

Comment: Ensure that the following columns are not strings. `Hispanic    White   Black   Native  Asian   Pacific`

Comment: Yeah, they are all numbers

Comment: @ Chukas Ebuka, this code snipets work for me. Let me know whether you get it right.

Comment: Can you explain to me what you did?